# C++ - optimize a line

Tags: c++, optimization

```
if ((*object)&1) { //object is int*
```

I am creating GC (Garbage collector) And I need to find a better way check
if the first bit in ptr's data is enabled. (And then do a code if yes)

This line takes 10% of my program running-time.
There is a way to optimize it with assembly? (In release mode it takes 3 lines)

By the way, I checked in another places with `&` operator and it takes a lot of performance.
It's not that the rest code is very fast. (C# takes 9 nano each object and mine is 17 nano)

After this line I disable this bit:

```
--*object;
```

It can help too?

Comment: The actual instructions cannot be made faster, but if you provide more context (the code inside the if, for example) there might be other things to do.

Comment: If `(*object)&1` is affecting performance then I don't think you can improve any further. I suspect you are the GC far too often in your code which leads to this. Can you optimize when you call the GC?

Comment: Could this be a symptom of failed branch prediction?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas But there's instructions that slower. Not any instruction takes one hz. For example: `jmp` is very very slow. If not the slowest.

Comment: @KingsIndian I set the GC to manually mode and allocated about 10 billion objects (Nodes that connect to each other) and then call the GC. The 10% it's with the allocation part...

Comment: Whats the distribution of the evaluation of that `If` statement. Is it something like `{TFTFTFTFTFTFTFT}` or more like `{TTTTTTTFFFFTTT}` if its the first case then its failed branch prediction.

Comment: I was about to suggest a faster way to clear the bit, but I see that Rob already wrote an identical suggestion and deleted it.  Rob, I encourage you to undelete that answer.

Comment: @ahenderson It's most true. (Object is reachable)

Comment: @DividedByZero: The problem is that in presenting a microproblem you are inhibiting other solutions. That is, maybe in the context of the rest of the code, multiple tests can be merged or reordered, maybe the branch can be avoided completely (depending on what you do internally(.

Comment: Could you explain what you are doing?  You say Object is an int pointer, so are you using a tag to determine some information?  Is there someway to not deref the pointer or add a prefetch to the code so that the deref hurts less?

Comment: Are you doing a check on a pointer to see if it's NULL? is so just do `if(!object) {` Why take the de-reference and &operator hit to performance.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I can't... This loop walks on the whole heap (Some fast heap I created) I can't avoid\merge\reorder it.

Comment: @stonemetal Nope... I need to walk on heap, this pointer is changing every step of this loop.

Comment: @ahenderson Nah I don't need it. The only things I need from this pointer is pointer to his type (Reflection) and his reachable-flag.

Comment: C#'s (.NET's) garbage collector is a highly optimized thing, especially in keeping track of objects that are supposed to GC. Hard to say what makes the difference with your GC implementation with that little concept and code examples given.
AFAIK .NET GC keeps track of several 'survival' levels of referenced objects. May be for usage in C++ you're better off using smart pointers. IMHO there's no real disadvantage, since even .NET garbage collector will end up with 'memory leaks' for circular references.

Comment: "allocated about 10 billion objects"!!!  Don't do this and expect GC to be fast!  And how big are these objects?  Even if they were only 1 byte that's 10Gb right there!

Comment: @j_random_hacker Oh sorry here is a copy paste `50000000` it's 50 million XD. Sorry my English is not that good. BTW they 8 bytes, next variable and type. (Pointer to type)

Comment: @g-makulik I am creating programming language. I need that GC. BTW I downloaded CLR's source but didn't find anything on their GC. Can you give me filename there that contains the collect method?

Comment: @g-makulik: I don't think the .NET GC will leak circular references. They work by finding out what is reachable. If none of the nodes in a cycle is reachable the whole cycle will go away.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I've seen so for unreleased delegates left on events (C#), but that was ages ago pre .NET 3.0.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Yeah and with generations and stuff. my GC's concept is like C#'s.

Comment: @DividedByZero Yuck no! I've just been participating a session about the inner workings of .NET GC long ago. I'm pretty sure they've been optimized it further meanwhile.

Comment: @DividedByZero: Even 50 million objects is a huge number -- there's no way you should be allocating that many 8-byte blocks. Use arenas. I don't understand how you need 50 million 8-byte objects if you're writing a language.

Comment: @j_random_hacker It's just a test to check if my GC is fast. BTW none use GC with game developing? (What I want to do is that) because GC give low performance.

Answer (score 2):

Nope.  `AND` is 1 machine instruction on every CPU ever made; there's no faster way to check the lowest bit.

Based on what you said about GC, it's possible that your performance problems stem from cache misses.

Comment: But there's instructions that slower. Not any instruction takes one hz. For example: `jmp` is very very slow. If not the slowest.

Comment: If you need to write `if` and you won't tell us what goes in its block, then compare and conditional-branch instructions are unavoidable costs. If the only thing inside the `if` block is a simple arithmetic/biwise logical operation, then there may be a faster straight-line hack that achieves it (e.g. if you just want to increment a counter you could get rid of the `if` entirely and just write `count += *object & 1;`).

Comment: Wow good idea but Before every object I have bit before it. There is no list of it. (And the size of those object can change between one to one)

Answer (score 2):

When you're down at this level of optimization, you should enable your compiler's assembly output so you can see the individual instructions that are generated. If you do so for this code I think you'll find that the `and` operation is a single instruction and can't really be optimized further.

Depending on the complexity of the code inside the `if` you might find that your registers are being exhausted and values are being reloaded more than necessary.

Comment: Nah this if took just 3 instructions. And the `and` instruction is like `jmp`. They not taking one hz in the CPU, They slow.

Comment: @DividedByZero, you can't make blanket statements like that. A jump might be slow, or it might be pipelined in parallel with other instructions and take no time at all depending on branch prediction.

Answer (score 1):

At least with GCC you can use the `__builtin_expect (condition, expected_result)` macro to optimize the compilers branch prediction for the if statement you show. But I doubt that this is the real reason for your performance problems (see my comment).

I would recommend to use C++ (11) smart pointers to solve your application's memory management aspects. Alternatively (to C++11 standard) you can use [boost SmartPtr library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm), [loki SmartPtr](http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/index.php?n=Idioms.SmartPointer) or other implementations.

Comment: I am creating programming language. I need that GC.

Comment: @DividedByZero If you're going to create a programming language core engine in C++ you might represent your core `Object` class instances (unfortunately you're not showing what these are) as adapted smart pointers (have a look at loki) and use branch prediction additionally.

Comment: Nah it not for engine. It's for everything. (C++...)

Comment: @DividedByZero Then I don't understand. You're crating a GC enabled language without a runtime engine and use C++ as intermediate language? Can you explain what's the role of C++ in your languages implementation?

Comment: @DividedByZero Is it more like a DSL what you're going to implement (since you mentioned game development)? Then you should have a look here: [link](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/DomainSpecificLanguage.html)

Comment: If I understood what is DSL then yeah my proglang'll be for every project type.